# Is it possible to convert if-else chains to nicer code with pattern matching and the switch statement in C#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pattern-matching

Is it possible to nicify this code with C# pattern matching and the switch statement?

```
    int target;

    if (a < b) target = 1;
    else if (a > b) target = 2;
    else if (c < d) target = 1;
    else if (d > c) target = 2;
    else target = e > f ? 1 : 2;
```

I tried but since switch requires a variable to operate on, I got stuck.

Comment: To each his own, but imo pattern matching is the opposite of nice and readable code.

Comment: Do not force a switch just to have a switch. What is wrong with ifs and else? If you want to have it short you can try ```target = (a < b) ? 1 : (a > b) ? 2 :  (c < d) ? 1 :  (d > c) ? 2 :  (e > f) ? 1 : 2; ```

Comment: Nice? No. You could do [tuple/positional pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#code-try-26) construct/deconstruction with your `a..f` variables, but it's going to be the furthest thing from looking 'nice'. Pattern matching is mainly meant for matching with *constant* patterns, not variables like what you're trying to do.

Comment: @martin thx thats good, will do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
int target;

if (a < b) target = 1;
else if (a > b) target = 2;
if (c < d) target = 1;
if (d > c) target = 2;
else target = e > f ? 1 : 2;
```

The first two `if` statements have no effect on the final value of `target`, since `target` will be overwritten by the last `if`.

So you can simplify this to:

```
int target;

if (d > c) 
    target = 2;
else 
    target = e > f ? 1 : 2;
```

This can be further simplified to:

```
int target;

if (d > c || e <= f) 
    target = 2;
else 
    target = 1;
```

You could write that using a tertiary operator:

```
int target = (d > c || e <= f) ? 2 : 1;
```

But I personally find using the `if` more readable.

---

[EDIT after OP's edit]

This code:

```
int target;

if (a < b) target = 1;
else if (a > b) target = 2;
else if (c < d) target = 1;
else if (d > c) target = 2;
else target = e > f ? 1 : 2;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
int target;

if (a < b || c < d || e > f)
    target = 1;
else 
    target = 2;
```

Or if you prefer:

```
int target = a < b || c < d || e > f ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: pardon me, i forgot the elses. thx for your work and input.

Comment: @citykid See my edit which addresses your update.

Answer (score 1):

It is defiantly possible to convert those conditions into [`switch expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) using all parameters as tuple and than matching parts of the whole tuple using `when` conditions. Review [patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#var-pattern) if you want some other conditions.

```
var r = (a, b, c, d, e, f) switch
{
    // property matching
    { a: var x, b: var y } when x < y => 1,
    { a: var x, b: var y } when x > y => 2,
    { c: var x, d: var y } when x < y => 1,
    // positional var with discards
    var ( _, _, x, y, _, _) when x > y => 2,
     ...
};
```

Note that you will not be able to reuse name as local names in each condition will try to shadow one in outer scope - so instead of `a < b` had to match other names - `x < y` in my case.

Whether it is "nicer" - up to you, but if you must have an expression rather than multiple statements it is an option.